# How to get ALL params of object?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module-params

If I want to retrieve a single parameter from a component the code is pretty simple, example:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

$params = $app->getParams('com_content');

echo $params->get('num_leading_articles');
```

This works though *only* if you know the exact name of the parameter you want to retrieve. Is there a way to get ALL params instead? Sometimes you may not know all the parameters of a  component, how can you get a list of those params if that's the case?

I'm on Joomla! 3.4

Comment: did you try using `print_r($params)` ? This contains all the parameters of `com_content` component.

Comment: `getParams()` returns the [Params object](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.Registry.Registry.html) with wich we use the `get()` method to retrieve a single parameter. The only property of this returned object is the `separator` path. Quite unconvenient, but considering the amount of parameters that can be set maybe it's an overkill (I would mostly use for debug or similar though, not in production).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the following:

```
$componentParams= JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');

var_dump($componentParams);
```

This will provide an object like so:

```
object(Joomla\Registry\Registry)[175]
  protected 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[503]
      public 'article_layout' => string '_:default' (length=9)
      public 'show_title' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'link_titles' => string '1' (length=1)
      etc....
```

Because it's a protected object, you will when of course need to use Joomla's `get()` method to access it, like so:

```
$foo = $componentParams->get('show_title');
```

If you'd like to get the params without knowing the name of them or without using `get()`, you can use a `foreach` loop like so:

```
$componentParams = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');

foreach ($componentParams as $key => $val)
{
    echo $key . ' - ' . $val;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if I have understood him right, I think he is after somehow getting in an array or something, all the params with a single function at once, without having to call the get() for each one...

Comment: @FFrewin - Updated ;)

Comment: Gah I found the issue, fact is that for not better known reasons, the dump from J!Dump extension wasn't returning correctly the output in the first place (though could be due to the protected properties). A raw `var_dump` got me what I was looking for.

Comment: Slightly OT, since I got issues with a tool I'm quite familiar with like [J!Dump](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/j-dump), is there any good alternative for it atm? I mostly develop with Firefox DEV, and Sublime Text.

Comment: @Gruber - I personally **hate** it, but PHPStorm may be a better text editor as it has advanced debugging tools.

Comment: Heh, many times PHPStorm name popped, but I have no particular love for IDEs, I'm just too used to Sublime features and simplicity.. Guess I'll need to find a way to make them both work for me :P

Comment: @Gruber - Agreed. I'm a Notepad++ user. Extremely fast and simple. I tend to stick to standard var dumps and Firebug for my debugging.

Comment: @Lodder It might sound silly, but I found I like Phpstorm a lot more now (than before) after styling it the same as Notepad++. Notepad++ is awesome though.